# How to compare pageviews in a conten group versus certain event happens in that pages using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, filtering, analytics-events

I have a custom search page in my website that uses several input forms.

I added an event `ga('send', 'event', 'Product', 'click')` whenever a user clicks on the product link in the search result list. There are couple other events triggered in the page that are not related to the search result.

I also have added content grouping for the search page since the URL can be really different between search pages based on the input forms.

How do I create a custom report that can show the difference between page views for the content group and the number of events mentioned above?

What have I done is:

- I added `Pageviews` and `Total Events` in a Metric Group
- I added `Page` as the Dimension.
- I added the content group as a filter.

But then I'm not sure if I should add the `Event Category = Product` and `Event Action = click` in the filters as I think it will also filter the `Pageviews`. (Turns out it does)

How should I do it?